# Dispatch from one nested navigator to another with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to send the user from a screen in one `StackNavigator` to another screen in another `StackNavigator`, both nested in a `TabNavigator`.

So if I have my `TabNavigator` as

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
  FirstTab: { screen: StackNavigator1 },
  SecondTab: { screen: StackNavigator2 },
});
```

and `StackNavigator1` has a screen `ScreenA`

```
const StackNavigator1 = StackNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  ScreenB: { screen: ScreenB },
});
```

and `StackNavigator2` has a screen `ScreenC`

```
const StackNavigator2 = StackNavigator({
  ScreenC: { screen: ScreenC },
  ScreenD: { screen: ScreenD },
});
```

I want to send the user from `ScreenA` to `ScreenC`.

I guess I should use something like

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenC' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

but I afraid `ScreenA` in `StackNavigator1` doesn't know about `ScreenC` in `StackNavigator2`, so do I need to use `react-redux`?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I solved it. I don't know if it is implementation detail dependent though.

Basically you get a `ref` to the nested navigator. Then you can call `this.ref._navigation.***`.

Here is how I did it - [Implementation detail worries - Calling navigate on nested Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43332027/1828637)

You can pass that `ref` around as wildly as you want - to as many other navigators. But really don't pass the ref, just pass the function you need out of there, like `this.ref && this.ref._navigation.navigate`.